# Draw an arrow such that this arrow gradually dims away?

Tags: opacity, graphics

How to draw an arrow such that this arrow gradually dims away?

Say the arrow head has `Opacity[1]`,
but the arrow end has `Opacity[0]`?

Thank you in advance! Here is the minimal code:

```
Graphics[{
  Black, Opacity[1], Arrowheads[Large], Arrow[{{2.5, 2.5}, {5, 5}}]
  }]
```

Here is an example of the [image]arrow:
I failed to manage to gradually dims the arrow away to the arrow end.

Answer (score 9):

```
Graphics @ 
 {Arrowheads[{{.1, 1, {Graphics[{Opacity[.1, Black], 
    Polygon[{{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}}]}], 1}}}], 
  AbsoluteThickness[5], 
  Arrow[Line[{{2.5, 2.5}, {5, 5}}, 
    VertexColors -> {Opacity[1, Black], Opacity[.1, Black]}]]}
```

[image]

```
Graphics @ 
 {Green, Rectangle[{3.9, 3.9}], 
  Arrowheads[{{.1, 1, {Graphics[{Opacity[.1, Black], 
        Polygon[{{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}}]}], 1}}}], 
  AbsoluteThickness[10], 
  Arrow[Line[{{2.5, 2.5}, {5, 5}}, 
     VertexColors -> {Opacity[1, Black], Opacity[.1, Black]}]]}
```

[image]

Replace `Opacity[1, Black]` with `Opacity[1, Purple]` and `Opacity[.1, Black]` with `Opacity[.3, Orange]` to get

[image]

Alternatively, without `Opacity`:

```
Graphics @ 
 {Green, Rectangle[{3.9, 3.9}], 
  Arrowheads[{{.1, 1, {Graphics[{GrayLevel[.9], 
        Polygon[{{-1, 1/2}, {0, 0}, {-1, -1/2}}]}], 1}}}], 
  AbsoluteThickness[10], 
  Arrow[Line[{{2.5, 2.5}, {5, 5}},
     VertexColors -> {GrayLevel[0], GrayLevel[.9]}]]}
```

[image]

Replace `GrayLevel[0]` with `Purple` and `GrayLevel[.9]` with `Lighter[Orange, .8]`  to get:

[image]

Comment: It seems a very smart way +1 thanks!!!

Comment: I will accept the answer in a few days if no better solutions show up. :) I like this

Comment: If using `Polygon`, `LinearGradientFilling` is an option.